# What is the correct usage of 犯險?

Tags: meaning

To improve my extremely bad listening ability, I am watching 蘭陵王。 I am currently at a point where the protagonist is pursued and his friend joins him, instead of fleeing. The friend comments:
[image]

I understand, that 豈有此理的豈 is written in new characters and that it is a rhetorical question. I think I understand the question:

> As a brother, how could I let fourth Prince brave the danger alone?

In so doing, I have assumed 犯險 to be 冒險。But none of my dictionaries contain it. When is 犯險 used? Does it differ from 冒險？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/2546/
>
> **犯**
>
> [1] [v] offend; violate; **go against**
>
> [2] [v] invade; attack; encroach on

「犯險」go against danger

「犯天威」go against  the wrath of Heaven (emperor)

「冒險犯難」take risk and go against disaster

It is not in that dictionary, but I would suggest "**go and face**" is also a good interpretation of 「犯」in this sense.

The main point is: "to 「犯」something formidable"  is to actively go against it, facing it, so your interpretation of " to brave" is quite direct and accurate.

> I have assumed 「犯險 to be 「冒險。But none of my dictionaries contain it. When is 犯險 used? Does it differ from 冒險？

*「冒險」 and 「犯險」 are basically the same, differ only in degree of activeness. You can move forward to 「冒險」,  or you can 「冒險」 by not taking action; but you have to move forward to 「犯險」.

*「以身犯險/以身冒險」(personally go against danger/personally taking risk)is a common four characters phrase, it mentions 以身 (with one's own body) to emphasize the  seriousness of the stake.

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/1428/
>
> **冒**
>
> [2] **risk; brave**; jeopardize

Answer (score 1):

犯险 is differ from 冒险。犯险 is often uesed in 以身犯险。And“做兄弟的岂能留四爷一人犯险” is the same as “做兄弟的岂能留四爷一人以身犯险”。
e.g 觊觎拆迁补偿以身犯险,伪造法院判决终被判刑。
    老汉高速公路骑自行车 只为捡柴方便以身犯险。
    军人们甘愿以身犯险来保卫我们的祖国。